# C# Xamarin.Forms: find Page which is hosting a View

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Actually i have a ContentPage described by XAML.
Inside this content page, i have a few custom XAML controls.
Into the custom XAML OnClick event, i'd like to throw a DisplayAlert().

This method is attached to a Page object.

How can i, from the code behind into my custom control, find the Page where my custom control stands ? Is there something similar to MyView.GetParentPage() ?

Thank you.

Comment: It's better to use [Acr.UserDialogs](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/42508/is-it-possible-to-use-acr-usedialog-with-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Excellent idea. Thank you for pointing me this 3rd party tool.